# Android: change the color of a bitmap

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, draw, paint

let's say i have this bitmap, which is a random shape painted all black, and say i want to be bale to change it color, does my bitmap have to be all painted white first or is there something else to it?

Comment: its not necessary that your bitmap should be painted white first you can set any time with any background

Comment: than why when i use the command drawBitmap (bitmap , matrix , paint (color green) ); my bitmap remains black.. is this is the way to do so or have i got it all messed up?

Comment: i think there must be problem something in paint (color green) thats why its not painting.pass only parameter paint and set color green in paint as paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

Comment: this is what i do currently, it doesn't work

Comment: bt u hv written drawBitmap (bitmap , matrix , paint (color green) ); where u hv set the color??

Comment: or you can change bitmap to imagview and set its background color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Canvas the way to alter the bitmap's color is to alter the bitmap itself. The steps involved are as follows:

Say you want to load an existing Bitmap you have somewhere and you want to tint it red somehow.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap);
```

After that you want to modify the bitmap's pixels before you paint it onto the Canvas. You create an int array that will holds all your pixels.

```
int[] pixels;
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

After that you need to modify the array (say, adding to the red component). However, right now all we have is int values inside a pixel array. R,G and B are all packed inside. How to retrieve them?

```
int red = Color.red(pixels[n]);
int green = Color.green(pixels[n]);
int blue= Color.blue(pixels[n]);
```

Then you modify the pixel's value by whatever you want, you could put it in a loop or however you like, and then put it back to the pixels array. Also, RGB values go from 0-255 because they are 8-bit values.

Right after that you would put them back using exactly the opposite function.

```
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

And then you're ready to go calling Canvas.drawBitmap();

Keep in mind that this process ought to be slow if you do it frequently, besides Canvas is a slow way of doing thing's if you're interested in real-time apps such as games.

Hope it helped!

Comment: first of all i tells me i need to initialize pixels, so i tbe int[] pixels = null; or also i have a compiling error.. second i can't enter the for (int n=0; n<pixels.length; n++) becuase pixels is null...

Comment: never mind, i used a double for loop :), it worked. thanks :)